# Virtualenv activated but python still running system version

Tags: django, python-2.7, virtualenv

I just trying to run someone else django project with their virtualenv but after activate its still runs the system python:

```
(virtualenv) tbosss@tbosss:~/Desktop/environment$ which python
```

/usr/bin/python

Comment: To check which python version using in virtualenv type `python -V`  and `which python` always shows available python in your system

Comment: it just shows version

Comment: Is it show desired python version? So, now whats your requirements?

Comment: venv is activated so it should show venv python but its showing system version

Comment: deactivate venv and activate again

Comment: You may verify the `activate` script used to reconfigure your path when you enable the venv. There is probably somthing that add `/usr/bin` before the correct path in `$PATH` variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update:

Antwane saids: *In my environment, which corrrectly return the path of python in the virtual environment.*

I've tested this too and he/she is right.

You might have some configuration error.

If help you some way you can:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

in order to have an alternative to `which`.

Comment: In my environment, `which` corrrectly returns the path of python **in** the virtual environment

Answer (score 0):

Try to print the content of `$PATH` variable when the venv is activated. You will probably find that:

- `/usr/bin` is present BEFORE the real path of your venv
- OR the venv path is NOT referenced in `$PATH`

In addition, you may try to print the content of `$VIRTUAL_ENV` variable:

```
echo $VIRTUAL_ENV
```

and verify that it contains the correct path.

Finally, you will have to dig in the environment and try to find why this configuration error appear.

And of course, if you are not interested to find why this happenned, you can just delete the virtual environment and create a fresh new one, there is a good chance everything work back.